# MySQL "cant create test file" , "Failed to set datadir or directory" , cannot connect with initial password

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am new to mysql and just installed MySQL Server 8.0 and workbench **(Windows 7)** and don't know exactly what is wrong. First i opened workbench saw the Local Host 3306 with user:root and clicked to connect. It asked for a password, **i don't know the password** (I tried empty password). I opened cmd as admin and tried commands 'mysql' and 'mysqld',
and got 'not a recognized command' for both. Then i navigated to where the mysqld.exe is located, **C:\Program Files\MySQL Server 8.0\bin** and tried executing the commands again and received the following:

```
C:\>cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: N
O)

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysqld
2020-01-29T19:19:01.443686Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MyS
QL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as process 8472
2020-01-29T19:19:01.446684Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test f
ile C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitiv
e_test.lower-test
2020-01-29T19:19:01.446685Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test f
ile C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitiv
e_test.lower-test
2020-01-29T19:19:01.447685Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir
 to 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\' (OS errno: 2 - No such file
or directory)
2020-01-29T19:19:01.462686Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-01-29T19:19:01.462688Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MyS
QL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.19)  MySQL Com
munity Server - GPL.

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>
```

**UPDATE:**
ok I created the directory **C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data** and changed its permissions for MySQL. The command 'mysqld' now doesn't return any errors. A SQL command line popped up asking for a password, again I never set one.  Back on cmd the command 'mysql -uroot -p - h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306' and again asked for a password. I cleared out the data directory which just had an error log and tried **'mysqld --initialize'** which added alot more to the data directory.
according to the MySQL manual here [Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/default-privileges.html)

it says a random password is generated in the error log, which it was ,however after trying that password in cmdafter 'mysql -u root - p' I received the following:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

tried the password it gave me on workbench and same result. I then removed the contents of the data directory and tried **mysqld --initiallize-insecure** which according to the manual allows you to connect with no password using command **mysql -u root --skip-password** and received the same error.

Comment: during the installation process you have to enter a password for root, else try empty password. btw. upgrade your system urgently to windows 10 1909 mysql doesn't mind

Comment: it was apparmor issue for me

Answer (score 2):

Easy answer is to go to where the errors states it wants the /data folder and create it.
You might have to change permissions on that folder; but trying to restart MySQL as you did should get further.

Comment: you were right i gave it file permissions and updated where im at. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How I fixed it:

Open command prompt and `run as an admin` then enter:

```bash
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Cluster 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe"

# threw up these errors:
# 2023-07-26T04:08:19.348337Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Cluster 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.28-cluster) starting as process 8132
# 2023-07-26T04:08:19.350234Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Cluster 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
# 2023-07-26T04:08:19.350308Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010091] [Server] Can't create test file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Cluster 8.0\data\mysqld_tmp_file_case_insensitive_test.lower-test
# 2023-07-26T04:08:19.350446Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013276] [Server] Failed to set datadir to 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Cluster 8.0\data\' (OS errno: 2 - No such file or directory)
# 2023-07-26T04:08:19.352089Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
# 2023-07-26T04:08:19.352226Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Cluster 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.28-cluster)  MySQL Cluster Community Server - GPL.
```

So, then I ran this to create the `data` directory then everything worked:

```bash
mkdir "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Cluster 8.0\data"
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Cluster 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe"

# no errors
```

which allowed it to create:

- auto.cnf
- binlog.index
- JayRizzoPAD.err

Why this comes up at all, is beyond me & really annoying for how long they have been around.

This should have been taken care of during setup. *sigh*